# How to filter table data between to dates using angular

Tags: angular

I want to filter my table between two dates the dates are in my database but I am told that my variable for the filter is not recognized

my component.ts

```
 this.Operations.filter('dateRange',function () {
          return function (Operations:any, startDate:any, endDate:any) {
            var result: any[] = [];
            var from_date = Date.parse(startDate);
            var to_date = Date.parse(endDate);
            console.log(from_date, to_date);
            Operations.forEach(ManagerOperation, function (operation:any) {
                if (operation.createdDate.split("T")[0] > from_date && 
            operation.operation.createdDate.split("T")[0] < to_date) {
                    result.push(operation);
                    console.log(result)
                }
            });
            return result;
            
        };
    });
```

my component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Enter Session Period</mat-label>
     <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker"  >
        <input matStartDate placeholder="From Date" [(ngModel)]="start_date">
        <input matEndDate placeholder="To Date" [(ngModel)]="end_date">
     </mat-date-range-input>
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>

 <tr *ngFor="let operation of Operations|dateRange:start_date:end_date">
```

I have this error  **No pipe found with name 'dateRange'**
please can you help me

Answer (score 1):

You have this line:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let operation of Operations|dateRange:start_date:end_date">
```

In that, you require the Operations collection to be *piped to a `dateRange` pipe*. So you could pick one of these options (among others):

- either implement your filter above as an Angular pipe or
- filter the array in the component, and leave the pipe outside.

The local filtering version may *seem* simpler; remove the pipe and things behind it, so you have something like this:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let operation of filteredOperations">
```

Your component will then have to be adjusted. E.g. to autofilter based on the from_date, change this:

```
<input matStartDate placeholder="From Date" [(ngModel)]="start_date">
```

to this:

```
<input matStartDate placeholder="From Date" [(ngModel)]="start_date" (ngModelChange)="filterOperations()">
```

Then you need to implement the `filterOperations` method:

```
class MyComponent() {
  Operations: any[] // set this however you did before.
  filteredOperations: any[] = [];


  ... // other stuff
  // This method is called each time your from_date is changed.
  filterOperations() {
    this.filteredOperations = this.Operations.filter(/* logic for filtering */);
  }
}
```

---

The dateRange pipe may look more complex: you need to create a pipe.

It would look like this:

In CLI:

ng generate pipe dateRange
// this will generate date-range.pipe.ts and its test file.

Now, edit the `date-range.pipe.ts` and edit it:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateRange'
})
export class DateRangePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(operations: any[], ...dates: Date[]): unknown {
    const dateFrom = dates[0];
    const dateTo = dates[1];
    return operations.filter(operation => {
      // logic to compare dateFrom and dateTo andthe operation.createdDate
    });
  }
}
```

With that, your code should work without changes in the class itself.